# gh auth login failing to authenticate (mkdir permission denied)

Tags: authentication, github, permissions

Currently trying to link my GitHub account to my new 14in MacBook Pro (2021). When running:

```
gh auth login
```

getting the following error:

```
gh auth login                                  
? What account do you want to log into? GitHub.com
? What is your preferred protocol for Git operations? SSH
? Upload your SSH public key to your GitHub account? Skip
? How would you like to authenticate GitHub CLI? Login with a web browser

! First copy your one-time code: 0EA1-6D8E
- Press Enter to open github.com in your browser...
failed to authenticate via web browser: mkdir /Users/myusername/.config/gh: permission denied
```

When I copy and paste the one-time code into my browser, GitHub says the authentication was successful. See screenshot:

[image: screenshot of successful authentication on browser]

Comment: I have edited the answer below to include the conclusion of your issue 5013, for more visibility.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in your issue [`cli/cli` issue 5013](https://github.com/cli/cli/issues/5013), the first thing to check is your permissions in `/Users/myusername/` or `/Users/myusername/.config`

```
ls -alrth /Users/myusername/
ls -alrth /Users/myusername/.config
```

The [OP William Cho](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9155011/william-cho) confirms:

> was able to fix using `chown`, and then `chmod` on `.config` to modify permissions.

Answer (score 0):

**Turning off the VPN worked for me.**

This worked for me and there wasn't a permission issue.
I was using MAC and MAC machine was not registered to github. Also, MAC was behind VPN was well. Turn off and try `gh auth login` and follow rest of the steps, you will be asked to put generated code in github.